# Is it bad practise to use a general function to query a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm writing a webapp which is to be used internally for a variety of tasks.
It uses a MySQL database which regularly needs to be queried for data.

I am aware of prepared statements and that they are best practise but given the large number of tables and joins I found it easiest just to write a general function that takes a query, runs it and returns the result.

I understand this could be vulnerable to SQL injection if it were on a live site but is there anything inherently bad about using this method? I am relatively new to interfacing between php and MySQL and would be interested to know the best practises for a repeatable method of running statements in a webapp.

Here is an example function I would use for `SELECT` queries.

```
function getSQLResultsPDO($query){
  $mydb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
  $sth = $mydb->prepare($query);
 if (!$sth) {
    echo "\n<pre>PDO::errorInfo():</pre>\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    echo "</pre>";
}
  $sth->execute();

  $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
  if (empty($result)){
    $result = false;
  }

  return $result;

}
```

Comment: It's not about SQL injection, it's about syntactical correctness! [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Are you really creating a new connection for every query youdo?

Comment: SQL injections is not a risk as long as you don't use user input into your queries. As long as the data of your queries/conditions are coming from end-user input (webform for example). Prepared statements are more secure, although an internal application is less prone to hacking...

Comment: @lonesomeday I'm really asking about the theory behind it. I suppose making a new connection each time is one reason why it's bad practise

Comment: @Bartdude you cannot be more wrong

Comment: everything about that script is bad practice... you didn't wrap your pdo call in a try catch block, therefore any errors would leak your db information.

Comment: @jay Only if the thrown exception is dumped to screen as is. That's not necessarily the case. If you catch the exception right inside the method, there's no real point in it being thrown in the first place. He's also not even using exception error mode.

Comment: @Bartdude: it is ENTIRELY possible to inject yourself, without any "user" data coming close to the query. **ANY** external data going into a query can be an injection source, whether it comes from a remote user form submission, or even something you JUST selected from the DB one step earlier.

Comment: @harryg: If nothing else, your code will be highly inefficient, opening a fresh DB connection **EVERY** time you call this function.Generally speaking, you should only ever open **ONE** connection to the DB and reuse it for the duration of the script's execution.

Comment: @Your common sense > Why please ? How would anyone inject any SQL in a query if there's no room for this ? Maybe I should have used "client information" instead of user input, as a querystring parameter coming from a webpage itself is also a risk

Comment: @Bartdude Please read something on the topic. Prepared statement is a must. No excuses. No exceptions. No long and windy considerations "is this data safe or not". Also read the first comment here.

Comment: @jayharris quite contrary. There shouldn't be a try..catch block. Moreother, 99% of PHP users who use it, actually use it indeed to leak database information.

Comment: @deceze he caught the prepare statement, not the db connection.

Comment: @deceze if the connect throws an error, it wouldn't get to the prepare statement.

Comment: @jay OK, true, if the connection fails, he'll get an exception. But again, **that's a good thing**. You'll just want to avoid dumping that exception with all its details to screen. You should *not* catch it immediately in this function though. Not being able to connect to the database is an *exceptional* event, throwing an exception is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 5):

I can only agree with the @jay harris' comment: "everything about that script is bad practice"

Although *the idea* of using such a function to deal with database is **the only sane choice**, the implementation is all wrong.

First of all, why do you think having such a function contradicts with prepared statements? Why not to add **just one extra parameter** - an array with data - and have both a function and safety?

Next, as you've been told already, do not connect for the every query but **once** per application.

finally, your way of error handling is wrong.

```
function getSQLResultsPDO($query, $params = array(), type = PDO::FETCH_CLASS){
  global $mydb;
  $sth = $mydb->prepare($query);
  $sth->execute($params);
  return $sth->fetchAll($type);
}
```

it is not very convenient, but at least it is usable and 95% safe.

After using this function for a while, you will discover that it's quite inconvenient to have only one. And eventually you will find that you need a set of functions. One to run DML queries which returns no rows, and some functions to return different kinds of results.

Compare these 2 codes:

```
$data = getSQLResultsPDO("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?", array($id));
if (isset($data[0]->name)) {
    $name = $data[0]->name;
}
//and
$name = getSQLscalar("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?", array($id));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm am now quite a bit more clued-up on the subject. I have actually gone a step forward and started to write my own class that uses PDO which contains the connection stuff in the `__construct()` method and I can then just call various query methods through it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good practice. If you look at frameworks, they implement something similar, except that it's more complex and they let you create your query by using different methods. The point of doing this is to centralise the querying, if all queries go through the same path, it's easier to modify something that concerns all queries. For example, if you wanted to change your database from MySQL to something else. Also, you can defend against injections in this central point.

So, your idea is good, but there are things that could be improved of course. You could create a single connection when opening the application, and use it for every query you run later on. If your query method is in a class, the connection could be a class attribute, for example, that is initialized in the constructor.

My suggestion is to look at how other people do it, and get inspiration from there. Look at how frameworks handle this stuff, for example.

Also, there is a nice MVC tutorial that also talks about this stuff, here it is :

http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials