# Should I include the user-input directly in the pdo prepared statement query?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I wanted to know what is the disadvantage of putting user-defined values in prepared query?

```
$query = "select * from tablename where ID=10";
$db->prepare($query);
$db->execute();
```

I wanted this because I do not want to create separate function for `$db->query()` and `$db->execute()` as both these functions behave and works differently while fetching rows.

I want only one function like `query()`, which would work for both normal and prepared statement queries.

`query()` would contain:

```
function query($query,$bindparameter = array()){
    $db->prepare($query);
    if($bindparameter) {
        // add them in prepared
    }
    $db->execute();
}
```

Should I write user-defined values directly in the query?

Comment: [here is your function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17322814/285587)

Comment: I am afraid you don't quite understand the meaning of a prepared query which the **only** purpose is to avoid including values into query directly.

Comment: ok. Do you think prepared statement is required for every query which has parameter? I hope no. Am I right?

Comment: No. Prepared query is a synonym for the query that has a parameter. You just can't run a query with a parameter without preparing it.